# Setting up a bunch of short/friendly redirect URLs

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite

I need to setup hundreds of short redirect URLs which follow this format:

`http://mysite.com/shorturl`

which will redirect to

`http://mysite.com/index.php?id=N`, where N is the ID corresponding to that shortcut.

What's the best way to do this.. should I be writing a ModRewrite line for each individually, or is there a better way to do this that incorporates storing a column in the database or a file?

Update: to clarify, the id N is an ID in the database.  The shorturl is a small phrase used for linking people to the page corresponding to that ID.

Comment: no.  shorturl will be a short, relevant phrase people can remember/link with

Comment: Sorry if I missed something, but where does `N` come from then?

Comment: Updated qstn to clarify.  will put any further clarifications needed up there as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you didn't want to do something like making

```
http://mysite.com/shorturl
```

redirect to

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?id=shorturl
```

And `index.php` can look up the correct `id` in the database from the `shorturl` and do the right thing.

Obviously, to do this, all you'd need is one line in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-z,0-9,_,-]+)/?$    index.php?id=$1 [PT]
```

Comment: Ah, so basically I would redirect to something like mysite.com/index.php?link=shorturl?  And store shorturl in the DB?

Comment: Yeah, I think that would be nice and direct; making a `shorturl` correspond to an `id` in the db which `index.php` would need to look up.