# Rewrite URL from pretty to ugly? /something -> ?a=somthing

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to use url rewrite to access this...

http://url.com/?a=value

via...

http://url.com/value

So that by using url.com/value I'm actually loading url.com/?a=value.

I'm assuming I need to put a rewrite in an htaccess file and then somehow detect this in index.php and pull out the field value? It's a bit beyond me unfortunately so would really appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Surely this has been asked before...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319805/setting-up-a-bunch-of-short-friendly-redirect-urls

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard htaccess file for "pretty" urls like the one you need:

```
#.htaccess file
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

then in your index.php you can get the initially requested path from the 'a' variable.

```
$path = $_GET['a'];
```

Answer (score 1):

This .htaccess code takes into consideration something like http://url.com/value?parameter=something

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)\&(.*)$ /$1?$2 [R]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)$ /index.php?a=$1&${QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```