# Web config request

Tags: php, url-rewriting, web-config

I don't have much experience with web.config files but what I am trying to do is redirect all requests to `index.php` only add `?url=REQUESTED_PAGE`

eg

if you went to `domain.com/about.php?query=string`

it would rewrite the url as `domain.com/about/` to the user
but process the url`domain.com/index.php?url=about.php&query=string`

the idea is to have nice looking user friendly urls whilst the index.php works out which page to show the user. (well am using smarty so which template to use)

EDIT: I am looking for help with web.config not .htaccsess I am restricted to the clients hosting and that isn't apache unfortunately and the only mod I can find that may or may not work with iis7.5 is £45 which I can not get funding for :(

EDIT: My latest attempt is

```
<rules>
  <rule name="page proc" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="domain.org.uk(.*?)\?(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}?url={R:1}?{R:2}" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

I think I am close but still not working

SOLVED :: !END RESULT!

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
            <rule name="page proc">
                <match url="(.*?)\/" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*?)(css|js|pdf|jpg|png|gif)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: To get a useful answer here, you need to provide more details (like which webserver) and show some attempt at research / solving your problem. If some specific problems arise, people will be glad to assist you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewrite URL from pretty to ugly? /something -> ?a=somthing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101063/rewrite-url-from-pretty-to-ugly-something-a-somthing)

Comment: ahh that one isn't for web.config.

Comment: and I am using windows iis 7.5 and php. I don't seem to have trouble finding the rewrite rules for httpaccsess files just web.config remains something of a mystery it is mainly the regex of the request I am struggling with that and my limited knowledge of how they work. I have found loads of individual page rewrite rules for we.config but I am looking for somethign more dynamic that uses regex to rewrite the url.

Comment: it is just an example as sometimes there may be a query string in the url that needs processing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'd need to create a `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will pass all requests (unless it's an existing file or directory) to your `index.php` script, and you'll be able to find out what the user requested in your PHP script by doing:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['url'];
?>
```

So you may split the passed `url` parameter at the slashes and pass it off to the correct controller or whatever.

The reason you don't rewrite existing files or directories is static files like images, stylesheets, JavaScript files etc. Otherwise requests for those files that *do* exist would still be passed to your `index.php` script.

Also, the `QSA` flag after the `RewriteRule` allows you to continue using query strings in URLs if you wish for things like search form and pagination if you prefer to use `$_GET` parameters for those too instead of URL segments.

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for your input, but I am using iis 7.5 which means no .htaccess file just a web.config, I can find loads of answers around google for .htaccess and a mod for £45 that may or may not work with iis 7.5 to let it use .htaccsess. but to do a url rewrite with web.config seems to be a closley guarded secret :(

Comment: Is this any help? http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution you asked:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Please tell me if it works.

Comment: Hi thankyou for your replay but this is for .htaccsess and I am looking for a we.config url rewrite, if I could use .htaccsess this would be so much easier lol